# Problems with installing Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, sql-server-2014-express

I am getting following error while trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
If anyone knows how is this fixed I'd be grateful for help.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRM0G.png)

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup
>
> Error reading from file C:\Users\aldin\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_shared_msi\PFiles32\SqlServr\120\DAC\bin\hcx5y0yq.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

Thanks in advance

I see that many of you put (-) on this question, I am currently learning about databases, tried installing sql server 3 times, 3rd time same error, restarted my laptop and did everything again, nothing changes.

Comment: It is 2021. You can install SQL Server 2019.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I am learning databases, so my tutor required SQL Server 2014, that's the only reason I am installing SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Did you verify that the user in whose name the installation is running has access? Otherwise, as this is not a programming issue, this might better be asked on another stack exchange site: Server Fault.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó 
Yes, I have admin rights and this is basically the only user account.
About second part of your comment, I guess I saw sql-server-2014-express tag, so I thought it'd be ok to post question like this here

Comment: Tags are to narrow the scope, but this doesn't mean that every question about the product belongs here - nevertheless you might get an answer here. I think you should add the tag of the OS as well.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Thanks for the suggestion, I did.

Comment: Tell your tutor to get with the program, 2014 was end-of-life'd 2 years ago. There is no material difference between that and 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file really might not be there.  Or it might be corrupt.  The first thing to try is to get a new copy of the media.  Unblock it after the download if required.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299

When you run it, it will want a location to extract the files.  Put it in a location to which you have full access.  The setup dialog will open automatically.  If not, run the setup.exe in the top level of the folder you extracted.  This might be all that you need.

There is a "Tools" option for "Installed SQL Server features discovery report" that might be of use.  If other editions of SQL 2014 are already present, they can be a problem...but not the problem you have yet.  (I never install express because it can cause issues installing DEV or STD editions.  It might become an upgrade instead of an install.)

The SQL 2019 DEV edition is free and can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads.  The discovery report in 2019 will be more inclusive (all versions up to 2019).

Check the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log" to see if there is more info in the log files.  The Summary.txt file will be the short version for the last run of setup.exe.  Sometimes there will be instructions on what to do (e.g., uninstall and retry).

Also check the Event Logs for messages that might relate to the install.

Sometimes a virus checker can quarantine valid files.

If it really is permissions, then try taking ownership (recursively) of the install media.

There are endless reasons for things to fail.  I hope it's just bad media.

Comment: I installed it this morning by running the setup file as administrator. Thanks for the help

Comment: Perhaps it's your UAC setting.  Normally you will be prompted to elevate if admin access is required.  Turning off UAC does not turn it off...just the notification.